# C# - Text box loads before frame

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, performance, textbox

I'll explain my problem as accurate as I can.

I have a win form that has a button which loads another form.

Here is the code of the button that loads the second form:

```
        ClearAll();

        if (Directory.Exists(TEMP_PATH))
            Directory.Delete(TEMP_PATH, true);

        if (CheckReq())
        {
            operationsCanceled = false;
            URL = urlTextBox.Text;
            downloadForm.Show();
            Download();
        }
```

This form "downloadForm" is created in the constructor of the main form.
The last line inits the download procedure, which fills the text box in the "downloadForm".

So, whenever I press the button, the text box and it's text loads almost a second before the rest of the controls and the form "downloadForm".

I thought that "downloadForm.Show()" will load everything in the screen before jumping to the next line, "Download()", so I don't get why this is happening.

Could it be because of the threads? The "downloadForm" has its thread and "Download()", which is a method in the main form is being executed in another thread?

So, basically, how can I resolve this? Is there a way to load the gui before I jump or call "Download()" without using the form's events or async/await?

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Comment: Why don't you call Download method in DownloadForms [Shown event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) handler?

Comment: @Reniuz: according to the documentation the Shown event only occurs the first time the form is shown - the event is not fired on subsequent showing of the form, so unless a new form is created this event is not the best solution. Maybe look at the Activated event : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms

Comment: Do you have any blocking context in Download method? For me the problem looks like download method execute something synchronously in the UI thread and blocking it until finished?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I tried using a simple "new EventHandler()" to add an event to the form "downloadForm" to check "downloadForm.Visible" and then call "Download()" and it works perfectly. I didn't want to use an event but I guess it's the simplest way.

Comment: I don't get it why cant you init download procedure in downloadForm? This for is for that purpose, isn't it?

Comment: @PaulF I know when event is raised. Why do you need to use Activated event? Do you want to *initiate* download process every time form is activated? I guess no!

Comment: The way I read the question was the button may be clicked multiple times to download different files - if that is the case then the Download method would only be called the first time the form is displayed - the documentation specifically says the event is only raised once - so you will need to choose an event that is raised on each display of the form.